# jQuery show elements with specific class

Tags: jquery, css, show

I would like to display all elements within a UL that have the class **.active** using jQuery.

Would my code look anything like this?

```
if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
      $( ".active" ).show();
    }
```

**My HTML markup**

```
<ul>
    <li><a>Menu item 1</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a>Menu item 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a>Menu item 2.1</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a>Menu item 2.2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a>Menu item 2.2.1</a></li>
                    <li class="active"><a>Menu item 2.2.2</a></li>
                    <li><a>Menu item 2.2.3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a>Menu item 2.3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Menu item 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

**My CSS**

```
ul li ul 
    {
        display: none;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

Comment: Is `$(this)` inside an event handler? What's the context?

Comment: all answers till now will be wrong if it is in a context or event

Comment: How do you show elements with specific class? during page load or button, li, a click or ajax loading or do you want to expand/collapse the menu during click?

Answer (score 1):

Could be even easier like:

```
$( "ul .active" ).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to check explicitly if your element has the active class just do this:

```
$('ul .active').show();
```

this will look for any element with the active class inside the ul and will show it

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through your `<li>`and display only those having `active` class:

```
<button onclick="init();">Test</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function init() {
        $('li').each(function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass('active')) 
                $(this).show();
            else $(this).hide();
        })
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example the code would be

```
if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
  $(this).show();
}
```

But I would target it directly:

```
$("ul .active").show();
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers seem to have missed that you need to show not only your hidden `.active`s, but also the hidden `ul`s that are contained in them. You can use a comma within a selector to do both at the same time:

```
$("li.active ul, li.active").show();
```

Or, to restrict it even further to something contained in a `ul`:

```
$("ul li.active ul, ul li.active").show();
```

May (or may not, depending on other css in how the page is rendered) be worth it to also remove the `overflow:hidden` with `.css("overflow", "auto")` or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            showOrHideMenu();
        });

        function showOrHideMenu() {
            $('#ulMainMenu li').hide();
            $('#ulMainMenu li.active').show();
        };
</script>


<ul id="ulMainMenu">
    <li><a>Menu item 1</a></li>
    ...
</ul>
```